# Add image slider counter via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following slider:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="container">
                <img id='slider-img' src='images/img1.png'>
                <div id='left_holder'><img onclick="slider(-1)" class='left' src="images/arrow_left.png"></div>
                <div id='right_holder'><img onclick="slider(1)" class='right' src="images/arrow_right.png"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the JavaScript that controls the image transitions:

```
var imagecount = 1;
var totalimage = 11;
function slider(element) {
  var image = document.getElementById("slider-img");
  imagecount = imagecount < totalimage ? imagecount + Number(element) : 1;
  if (imagecount < 1) {
    imagecount = 1;
  };
  image.src = "images/img" + imagecount + ".png";
}

window.onload = function() {
  slider(0);

}
```

I have 11 images at the moment in an images folder and I would like to add a counter to the bottom right of the slider. Something like 1/11 etc... and I would need it to wrap around of course so after 11/11, clicking on the right arrow will show a caption of 1/11.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a `div` to show the information.  You already know the count and the total.

```
<div id="showCount"></div>
```

And in the JS:

```
var showCount=$('#showCount');
function slider(element) {
  var image = document.getElementById("slider-img");
  imagecount = imagecount < totalimage ? imagecount + Number(element) : 1;
  if (imagecount < 1) {
    imagecount = 1;
  }
  image.src = "images/img" + imagecount + ".png";
  showCount.text( imagecount + '/' + totalimage );
}
```

BTW, you do not need a semi-colon at the end of the `if`.

**Update**:  Use CSS to position the div wherever you need it. I do not recommend using JS for that.

Comment: Great thanks for the answer. Now how can I position this div so its on the bottom right corner of my slider?

Comment: `showCount.text(element +'/'+imagecount);` returns an empty array

Comment: Should it be `showCount.text(imagecount + '/' + totalimage);`?

Comment: Upvoted as his answer works correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/juL4zLpt/ 
If your solution is returning an empty array then you may need to debug it some more.

Comment: Updated code sample to use `imagecount` and `totalimage`.